# How to group duplicate key field and create new column for the values

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I'm doing report using iReport 3.0.0 with java.
I need to query from A table which has **ID** and **Name** field join with B table that has **Value** field.

One Id can has more than one value.. So..

I have table as below;

ID           Name     Value

====      ====      ====

A              ABC            1

A              ABC            1

B              BCD            1

C              CDE            1

I have to read the data as:

ID           Name     Value

====      ====      ====

A              ABC          1,2

B              BCD          1

C              CDE          1

or


ID           Name     Value1    Value2

====       ====      ====       ====

A              ABC          1               2

B              BCD          1

C              CDE          1

is it possible to write this with sql without program?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listagg` function - it concatenates the values.

```
with 
A as (
  select 'A' id, 'ABC' name from dual union all
  select 'B' id, 'BCD' name from dual union all
  select 'C' id, 'CDE' name from dual
),
B as (
  select 'A' id, '1' value from dual union all
  select 'A' id, '2' value from dual union all
  select 'B' id, '1' value from dual union all
  select 'C' id, '1' value from dual
)
select A.id, A.name, 
       listagg(B.value,',') within group (order by B.value) list_of_values
from   A join B on A.id = B.id
group by A.id, A.name
```

Consider that there is limitation for the lenght listagg result, 4K characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-:

```
SELECT Distinct id,Name,Value = STUFF(
(
select ',' + cast(row_number() over(partition by A.id,A.name order by value)as varchar(100)) 
from YOURTABLENAME A 
where A.id = B.id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''
)
From
(
select  row_number() over(partition by id,name order by value) as r,id,name 
from YOURTABLENAME
)B
```